# Approach for differentiating "PEOPLE" in Named Entity Recognition

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, named-entity-recognition

I am using Spacy's pertained model to identify people in the IMDB movie reviews dataset. While the model identifies people in the reviews, I want to find out people who are characters of the movie as opposed to the director or the hero name. What would be an approach to achieve this? (assuming we can use any other data source).

Comment: You could use a resource like dbpedia to identify actors and fictional characters. For example: http://dbpedia.org/page/Batman for a fictional character and http://dbpedia.org/page/Natalie_Portman You could use a tool like DBpedia spotlight for the linking itself https://www.dbpedia-spotlight.org/

Comment: Great resource, +1.